# Why double results when call echo to output to file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmi, wmic

I am trying to generate DiskDevices.ini file about disks/drives.

This is [my batch](https://pastebin.com/S1HfcqKW).

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "InputFile=DiskDevices.ini"
IF EXIST "%InputFile%" (DEL /f /q "%InputFile%")
SET /A "TotalDevices=0"
SET /A "Index=0"
@FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=*" %%G IN ('
"WMIC PATH Win32_DiskDrive GET Index /format:csv 2>NUL"
') DO (
    SET /A "TotalDevices=TotalDevices+1"
    SET /A "Index=Index+1"
    >>"%InputFile%" CALL ECHO [Device_%%Index%%]
    @FOR /F Tokens^=* %%G IN ('
    "WMIC PATH Win32_DiskDrive GET Caption,Size /value 2>NUL"
    ') DO (
        @FOR /F Tokens^=* %%H IN ("%%G") DO (>>"%InputFile%" CALL ECHO %%H)
        )
)
>>"%InputFile%" CALL ECHO [Total Devices]
>>"%InputFile%" CALL ECHO Value=%%TotalDevices%%
PAUSE
```

Results is loop two times.

```
[Device_1]
Caption=Samsung EVO
Size=162536803840
Caption=Kingston USB Device
Size=31718510080
[Device_2]
Caption=Samsung EVO
Size=162536803840
Caption=Kingston USB Device
Size=31718510080
[Total Devices]
Value=2
```

I need same this:

```
[Device_1]
Caption=Samsung EVO
Size=162536803840
[Device_2]
Caption=Kingston USB Device
Size=31718510080
[Total Devices]
Value=2
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have nested two `for /F` loops that are gathering basically the same information, that is why you get duplicates.

---

What about this approach, which uses the `Index` property for the `[Device_#]` header as well as for a `where` clause of the inner `wmic` query:

```cmd
@echo off
set "COUNT=0"
> "DiskDevices.ini" (
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ('wmic DiskDrive get Index /VALUE 2^> nul') do (
        for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ("%%J") do (
            echo [Device_%%I]
            for /F "delims=" %%H in ('wmic DiskDrive where "Index=%%I" get Caption^,Size /VALUE 2^> nul') do (
                for /F "delims=" %%G in ("%%H") do (
                    echo(%%G
                )
            )
            set /A "COUNT+=1"
        )
    )
    echo [Total Devices]
    call echo Value=%%COUNT%%
)
```

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl, I tested your batch, did not DiskDevices.ini which created/generated. Test on Win10 x64 1809.

Comment: I just found a mistake in the code, though I have to admit I didn't have a chance to test it yet...

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl, I tested your new-batch, did not DiskDevices.ini which created/generated. When add REM to for /F "delims=" %%H in ('wmic DiskDrive where "Index=%%I" get Caption^,Size /VALUE 2^> nul') do.........then the DiskDevices.ini created.


[Device_0]
[Device_1]
[Total Devices]
Value=2

Comment: Oops, there was an opening parenthesis missing in that `for /F %%H` loop, fixed now...

Answer (score 0):

Because you're getting the list of devices twice. Do everything in one loop or add a `where` condition with `Index` value to the second `wmic` call to filter out the other devices.

Comment: please elaborate on your answer / add some code to improve it.